# Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'reactive'

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I want to use ReactiveSwift.

1. Podfile

`pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 6.0'`

2. `$ pod install`

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import ReactiveSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        button.reactive.xxx { ... }
    }
}
```

I have only this error, so I can run when I comment out `button.reactive.xxx { ... }`.

Tank you.

Comment: How does reactive work? Does it have an _extension_ on `UIButton` that adds the `reactive` member, or are you suposed to use some custom `UIButton` subclass (instead of `UIButton` itself) that **does** have that property?

Comment: By the way, the cocoa pods part seems to be working, otherwise the compler would complain about the `import ReactiveSwift` line.

Comment: I solved this problem when I change `import ReactiveSwift` to `import ReactiveCocoa`!  But example code seems to work with `import ReactiveSwift`. Is there any wrong in my project?

Comment: So I guess it _is_ and `extension` on `UIButton` that is defined in **ReactiveCocoa** (_not_ ReactiveSwift)

Comment: I see.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as @NicolasMiari suggested - Reactive Cocoa is split into several parts (since version 5.0 anyway).

[Reactive Swift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) contains the implementation of the core primitives (`Signal`, `SignalProducer`, `Property`, `Action`) and operators. Notably, this is platform independent.

[Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) is built on top of Reactive Swift and adds `UIKit` and `AppKit` specific extensions for iOS/macOS via the `.reactive` property.